# Wrong returned value in main function?

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

I previously read that 0 in C-Language refers to false while 1 is true.
And have noticed that the main function returns 0 but why is that? in case all of my code ran successfully it should return true (1).
Another related question, I still can't understand who can use the returnable value? since no other function called the main function inside my program so nothing can know if my program ran well or not.
I am a little bit confused.

Comment: OS asks main.. did anything wrong happen? It returns error code 0.. meaning nothing wrong.. Also, who can use the returned value? A parent process can.. For example if you create a child process and it returns -1 or something, the parent can know that it failed to do its duty.

Comment: Did your program fail? No, it didn't... so it returned zero (aka false)

Comment: Essentially main returns an integer error code if error happens else zero (=NO ERROR ALL FINE). C still interprest 1 as true and 0 as false if used as such in boolean expressions

Comment: It is not a common convention for C functions to return true/false for success. It is much more common to return 0 on success or an error code on failure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's essentially what @Brandon already said in the comments.

`main` is supposed to return the [exit/error code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of the program. In the Unix convention, `0` is used to indicate *no error* (the error value is "false"). And then positive values are used for indicating that there is an error and what error it was.

Comment: Never thought of 0 as "error value is false".  That's a nice way to think about it.

Comment: Not just positive values. But negative values too. I've seen programs return -9 when killed or -1, etc. :)
but anyway, +1 from me.

Comment: @Brandon Not on Unix.

Comment: Worth mentioning too that this is the only function where it will return 0 if you don't specify a return and it falls off the end of the block.

Answer (score 8):

Your logic would make sense if the return value of `main` were interpreted as a Boolean value, but it isn't. Returning from the initial call to `main` is like calling the `exit` function: It reports a termination status to the system you're running on.

Standard C specifies 3 portable exit statuses:

- `0`, indicating success
- `EXIT_SUCCESS`, also indicating success
- `EXIT_FAILURE`, indicating failure

(The last two are macros defined in `<stdlib.h>`.)

On Unix, any 8-bit value (0 .. 255) is allowed. All non-zero values are interpreted as error codes. There is no universal convention for what any given number means, just that `0` represents success and anything else some kind of failure.

As for who can use the return value: On Unix, a parent process can use `wait` or `waitpid` to get the exit status of a terminated child.

---

In the C standard library, functions that perform an action generally don't return a true/false status. (Tests such as `islower` or `isdigit` do, but they don't have any other effects.) For example, `remove` (which deletes a file) returns `0` on success and `-1` on error. This is also a common pattern with Unix system calls. For exmple, `open` returns a file descriptor (a non-negative integer) on success and `-1` on error.

Answer (score 2):

It's really just about the kind of question you ask a program when it finish.

Case 1:

> Did you fail?

Case 2:

> Did you pass?

In the first case a "good program" will return false (aka zero)

In the second case a "good program" will return true (aka non-zero).

Consensus is to use Case 1, i.e. "Did you fail?". Therefore a non-failing program returns zero to say "I did not fail".

The benefit of this approach is that non-zero values can be used to expressed different kind of failures while zero is alway "no failure"

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between what the C *language* considers `true` (non-zero) or `false` (zero) and what value(s) the *operating system* uses to indicate a normal program termination.

To be strictly correct, C programs should exit with a code of either `EXIT_SUCCESS` for normal program termination or `EXIT_FAILURE` for abnormal termination.  `EXIT_SUCCESS` will map to whatever code the underlying platform uses to indicate success, which may or may not be `0`.